# How do I write a pre-execution script to change the default save folder in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

If I want to save a layer created with any tool I use, I need to navigate through the Save to file... option and navigate to my Project folder each time if I want to save my output with the rest of my data.

I am able to enter a name and file type into the output section (instead of just [Create temporary layer]), but when I run the tool it saves the output to the Documents folder on my C Drive (C:\Users<username>\Documents).

It would be so much more convenient and time saving if I could just type it into output box.

I've found that this question ([Change default saving folder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367060/change-default-saving-folder/367066#367066)) had similar issues, and was told to "specify a pre-execution python script which" ... "could be written to set the save folder".

I have no idea how to do this, and am seeking any help that can be provided here.

I can see that there is also an unanswered thread that is still being commented on this year (with others also hunting for an answer to this) here:
[Change default "save as" folder QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183808/change-default-save-as-folder-qgis)

Comment: Have you tried to change the path **manually** in the `Output folder` in the answered question: [Change default saving folder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367066/63384)?

Comment: I assumed that was where temporary layers were stored (as it as set to a folder in my AppData, rather than Documents where the files were saving to). Upon changing it to a different folder, the files did actually save there... so thank you for that.

Comment: Any thoughts on the second part of my question - regarding how to automatically link that location to the folder set as Project home?

Comment: @Erik were you able to write some code to change the default output folder (as suggested by @ahmadhanb) so that it would always be set as the specific project folder?

Comment: I've added an answer to the following question that includes createing a macro to set default file locations - it's not a pre processing script but it might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183808/change-default-save-as-folder-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you so much for going out of your way to comment here! I'll give this a try over the next few days, and let you know how it goes for me